# Why did physics departments pivot away from applied and defense work?

Tags: united-states, physics, industry

During the 50s, 60s, 70s there was pretty intense cross disciplinary work between physics and engineering departments and industry with a focus on the US arms industry. This appears to almost have completely stopped among physic departments and a lot of them have shifted into increasingly esoteric and less applied areas.

What caused this pivot? As a whole it appears only engineering departments are really working on applied areas anymore.

Comment: I think it was largely acknowledged in hindsight by prominent physicists of the time that the collaborations were a mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cold war started shortly after WW-II. The moon/space race then also began (Sputnik - 1957). Doctoral students in STEM fields were able to get full fellowships for doctoral study (as I did). Undergraduates could get very favorable student loans that were forgiven for those that went into teaching (also myself). That all ended in the very early 70's after we beat the "Ruskies" to the moon in 1969. I don't think Physics was special, but it *was* rocket science for quite a long time.

The academic marketplace also fell apart between 1970 and 1972.

But the arms industry has always lobbied heavily and successfully for government funding.

Additionally, in that same period, the US economy was very good so funds were readily available. Lots of factors.

Why it mostly went away is a different story, but there is a tendency to succumb to the fallacy of the last move. After a seeming win, people think that the "other side" has no more moves, so attention shifts elsewhere. That has been a blunder performed throughout history. After COVID seems to go away we lose focus and forget that another pandemic might easily occur at any time, so medical research starts to lose money...

Same old, same old.

Comment: Hmm those makes sense but it also feels like there was a fundamental character shift.

Comment: Well, in the US, the administration changes every 4 or 8 years and even when it lasts 8, changes are made in the agencies at the four year mark. There was a lot of turmoil because of Vietnam and the end of the Nixon era.

Comment: Makes some sense in regards to administration changes but my overarching feeling is that the academic departments basically turned away from these areas on purpose. It's increasingly hard to find professors who take pride in this work(or are even capable of doing it because of clearance issues). I know a few but it's basically kept secret, not for legal reasons but for social.

Comment: I doubt that a lot of federal money for research goes unclaimed. There was a huge cutback. And in the cold war - Vietnam era there were a lot of anti war academics. I think your guess is wrong. I've had to take loyalty oaths to study, actually (late 60's IIRC).

Comment: It might even be that the proportion of STEM academics who wouldn't take defense department money was higher around 1965-1970 than now. But lots of things have changed. End of the Soviet era, etc. These things are all connected.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'm not in physics(which is what my question was on) but for example the AI department where I studied basically rejected a bunch of DoD funding because the only professors who passed the qualifications for it were philosophically opposed to the target application. I was forced to listen to multiple ethics lectures attempting to demonize the areas of weapons development so there's some pretty strong pushes among segments of either administration or academics in this.

Answer (score 9):

The premise is incorrect.  Applied research is widespread in physics departments.

Physics departments do not research radar, aerodynamics, nuclear weapons, and so forth because their involvement in that research is not necessary anymore.  They work on new applied stuff that's more relevant to their capabilities.

Comment: I don't think so, looking at the output of the physics departments at the universities I have been in there's a huge gap between what is deemed as "applied physics" and building functional things which was the focus in the past.

Comment: Also there's always more to be done on radar, aerodynamics, nuclear...none of the fields are complete in so far as no longer being relevant.

Comment: @FourierFlux What are you basing this assessment on? A cursory read of the Wikipedia page on the history of radar, for example, shows that academics were not the ones who developed functional, useful radars: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_radar

Comment: @FourierFlux Please note the difference between "research is not necessary anymore" and "their involvement in that research is not necessary anymore".  If it can be done outside a physics department, why do it inside a physics department?   Physics departments have plenty of special expertise which is relevant to application.  It just is different special expertise from decades ago; things from decades ago are no longer special.

Answer (score 5):

I think one can object to the question in many different ways, and here are several:

*1.* You say "a lot of [departments] have shifted into increasingly esoteric and less applied areas". In some sense, physics has never been about applied research -- the wikipedia definition of physics reads as follows:

> Physics is the natural science that studies matter, its fundamental constituents, its motion and behavior through space and time, and the related entities of energy and force. Physics is one of the most fundamental scientific disciplines, with its main goal being to understand how the universe behaves.

And that has always been true: Maxwell, Planck, Einstein, Heisenberg, and nearly every other titan of physics you could name from the time before the 1950s was interested in *fundamental* questions and not nearly as much in applications. You can call these esoteric, but they go back a very long time -- particle physics as we know it started in the late 1800s after all.

*2.* There was a time when physics departments shifted to *also* include research in astronomy, astrophysics, materials sciences, and a number of other disciplines. Then people realized that that is not a great fit given the philosophical origins of physics (as outlined in the quote above) and they split the department. So many universities today have physics departments that investigate, well, physics. And then they have astronomy or astrophysics departments, and they have (typically quite large) materials sciences departments. But nearly every physics department will have a sizable number of people who do fundamental work on the characterization and development of solid state matter, and it's really not very useful to say that that is not applied in some sense: for example, numerous physicists have gotten Nobel prizes for work on lasers, and numerous more for work on materials with specific electric, thermal, magnetic properties or their interaction. When they did this work, it was all about fundamental properties, but it turned out to be very applicable. Nearly every one of your electronic devices around you will have a dozen of these materials built into them somewhere. It would not have happened without solid state physics researchers in physics departments.

*3.* Many researchers, in many departments, work across disciplines. There continue to be connections between physics departments and engineering departments that turn on the idea that many fundamental properties discovered about matter happen to have practical applications (see above). It is simply not true that the connections between physics departments and engineering departments no longer exist. It may be true that these collaborations today revolve less around national defense topics, but that's because (i) national defense today knows most of what it needs to know about the materials it used (which wasn't the case with nuclear bombs for several decades), (ii) national security in the US today revolves a lot more around making sure that we continue to be technologically superior, and this is furthered by materials sciences more than knowing about the properties of Plutonium that we don't already know to 3 digits of accuracy.

*4.* It is simply false that departments are not involved in defense research. There continues to be a lot of research about materials that have weapons applications (think, for example, thermal shielding, radiation hardness, ...). A large number of physicists are also involved in experiments such as the National Ignition Facility, which is and has always been primarily a national defense facility built with the goal of investigating ways to build nuclear weapons without actually testing them.

Comment: Solid state is definitely the most relevant area most physics departments work on but I don't really agree with the idea that physics was always about fundamental research(though it is moreso today). Again during the time frame I listed you saw physicists actively involved in many more projects focused on developing end products which is no longer the case.

Comment: You have *always* seen physicists involved in applied topics, and you continue to see so. I mean, go back to the physicists in the mid-1800s in Britain who figured out basically all of (theoretical) thermodynamics while also building steam engines. And there were plenty of theorists who looked at quantum field theories in the 1950s and 1960s and 1970s -- all of the particle physics standard model was built in these decades. I really do think that you're perceiving patterns where there are none as stark as what you proclaim.

Answer (score 3):

Another factor is that universities tend to be much bigger now than they were in the 1950s.  With size comes more departments.  It's impractical to have 100 departments each with 3 professors, but it's much more practical to have 100 departments each with 10 professors.  This means that, in the 1950s, many universities did not have the array of engineering departments they have today.  Even a large university in the 1950s would have had a civil engineering department and a mechanical engineering department and maybe an electrical engineering department, but they probably didn't have materials science or industrial engineering or any of the other more specialized engineering disciplines.  Moreover, many of the older engineering departments still came from a 19th century way of doing engineering that ignored physics and calculation (even basic Newtonian mechanics) in favor of just testing models until they broke and adding 10% for a safety margin.

As a result, many of the people who would be found in, for example, a materials science department today had to choose between being in a civil engineering department or a physics department, and they found the physics department a better fit.  This means you had people who were considered physicists back then but would be considered engineers now doing applied research.

What's changed is not that physicists stopped doing applied research, but rather that the people doing applied research stopped being called physicists as new names for what they were doing emerged.